# Form post failing to bind to strongly-typed model MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

** **UPDATE** **

The problem here was that the top most container object of type **CompleteService** was named "*service*" in my controller POST method below. The default model binder was getting confused because this object and the internal property **Service** which was also named "*service*". Due to this duplicate the default model binder was failing.

---

For some reason when I am posting my strongly-typed form back to my controller the model is not actually capturing any values, even though I can view the Request.Form in the debugger and see the values that I expected that are URL encoded. I have included the **Model**, **Controller Action**, **View**, and **Request.Form** values as a URL encoded string below.

The only hunch I have is that perhaps the models constructors could be 'newing up' an object over the data. However, I do not have a firm understanding on how the Model Binder actually works in terms of execution.

Here is my outer and inner **Models** *which has been shortened for readability.*

```
public class CompleteService
{
    public Service Service { get; set; }

    public List<XrefSubMenuToServices> Xrefs { get; set; }

    public CompleteService()
    {
        this.Service = new Service();
        this.Xrefs = new List<XrefSubMenuToServices>();
    }

    public CompleteService(Service service, List<XrefSubMenuToServices> xrefs)
    {
        this.Service = service;
        this.Xrefs = xrefs;
    }
}
```

Inner Model below

```
public class Service
{
    // Unique Id
    [DisplayName("Service Code")]
    public short ServiceCode { get; set; }



    // Service Specific Properties

    [DisplayName("Contact History Flag")]
    public bool ContactHistoryFlag { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Customer Type")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string CustomerType { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Member Branch Service Flag")]
    public bool MemberBranchServiceFlag { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Membership Required Flag")]
    public bool MembershipRequiredFlag { get; set; }

    ...

    // Properties that are not part of the Service Table
    private GeneralServicesMTL _mtl;

    public SelectList CustomerTypeDropDown
    {
        get
        {
            if (_customerTypeDropDown == null)
            {
                _customerTypeDropDown = _mtl.GetTypeAsDropDown("CustomerType");
            }
            return _customerTypeDropDown;
        }
    }

    ...

    public Service()
    {
        _mtl = new GeneralServicesMTL();
    }
```

Here is my **Controller Action**:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddService(CompleteService service)
    {
        // Code doesn't expect nulls
        if (service.Xrefs == null)
        {
            service.Xrefs = new List<XrefSubMenuToServices>();
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(service);
        }

        try
        {
            _mtl.SubmitCompleteService(service);

            return RedirectToAction("AllServices");
        }
        catch
        {
            // Add the error code to the page 
            TempData["Error"] = "There was a problem creating the service. Please try again.";

            return View(service);
        }
    }
```

Here is my **View** (Partial Views can be added if requested, but I don't think that's the problem)

```
@model Admin.MVC.Models.GeneralServices.CompleteService
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Service";
}

@Html.ActionLink("Return to All Services", "AllServices", "GeneralServices", null, new { @class = "col-xs-offset-1" })

@if (TempData["Error"] != null)
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary((string)TempData["Error"]);
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("AddService", "GeneralServices", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", @class = "form" })){

    <div class="container">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Service, "ServiceEditor") <!--Serivce-->
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="container">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Xrefs, "MenuSubMenuEditor") <!--Menu/SubMenu-->
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-2" value="Create Service" />
    </div>

}

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/General Services/AddServiceScripts.js")"></script>
}
```

And finally, this is the value that is being captured in **Request.Form** that is being viewed from inside the controller action above while debugging.

**Without the Optional Xrefs Property**

```
[System.Web.HttpValueCollection]    {Service.ServiceText=Test+Service+1&Service.ServiceUrl=NONE&Service.ServiceTypeCode=1&Service.ServicePriority=180&Service.UrlUsageType=A&Service.ContactHistoryFlag=false&Service.MembershipRequiredFlag=true&Service.MembershipRequiredFlag=false&Service.RiderCategory=N%2fA&Service.CustomerType=A&Service.MemberBranchServiceFlag=false&Xrefs.MenuLocationTypeCode=}    System.Web.HttpValueCollection
```

**With the Optional Xrefs Property**

```
[System.Web.HttpValueCollection]    {Service.ServiceText=Test+Service+2&Service.ServiceUrl=NONE&Service.ServiceTypeCode=2&Service.ServicePriority=329&Service.UrlUsageType=P&Service.ContactHistoryFlag=false&Service.MembershipRequiredFlag=false&Service.RiderCategory=N%2fA&Service.CustomerType=M&Service.MemberBranchServiceFlag=false&Xrefs.MenuLocationTypeCode=3&Xrefs%5b0%5d.MenuLocationTypeCode=3&Xrefs%5b0%5d.MenuCode=1&Xrefs%5b0%5d.SubMenuCode=1&Xrefs%5b0%5d.DisplayOrder=25}   System.Web.HttpValueCollection
```

I am completely stumped by this and have no idea why the model binder would be failing to bind the form value collection to the model. Any insight I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: I think this relates to the way you're creating the form elements ie using `EditorFor`. Have a look at what gets rendered for the list items, they should be named using an index, so you may need to create the inputs by iterate over the collection using a `for` loop.  Do a search for `MVC form post list`.

Comment: @markpsmith I am actually handling that with the scripts. The List<XrefSubMenuToService> is actually optional, just it cannot be null. I followed haaacked.com wonderful article for ensuring the the data is in a valid format. I can post an example of the HttpValueCollection including some List items if you would find it useful.

Comment: What happens if you set the two objects separately as parameters? `Service service, List<> Xrefs`

Comment: @ThomasBoby if I understand you correctly, you mean to try and create a new constructor that accepts both objects as populated objects? Let me go try.

Comment: Not a constructor, just the action. See if it'll bind the two objects as two separate parameters, then make the top level object yourself. `AddService(service service, list...) `

Comment: @ThomasBoby Correct me if I am wrong, but then my model will break as I cannot strongly type both Models in the view, and thus I would lose data during the form post.

Comment: Unless I've completely misunderstood the problem, sure you can. Your view model does not have to match your post models, and in fact the model binder has no idea about the view model. It infers from field id and action parameter names and types, and recursive property types.

Comment: @ThomasBoby it worked! I can't believe it was that simple. If you'd like to try and answer by pointing out my flaw I will gladly mark you as the correct answer. If not, I can answer it myself and try and research the issue further to really find out why the original implementation was wrong.

Comment: I'll write it up in a bit, along with some possible solutions for binding the `CompleteService` :)

Comment: @ThomasBoby. With due respect all your comments are plain wrong. The reason its not binding is because the model contains a property named `Service` and the name of the parameter in the POST method is also named service.

Comment: @DanielSiebert, If the dupe do not solve your issue and its only the `Xrefs` property which is not binding, then its because your not using `EditorFor(x => x.Refs, "MenuSubMenuEditor")` correctly - you cannot use a template name when using a collection. Your `EditorTemplate` needs to be named `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/XrefSubMenuToServices.cshtml` (i.e. the same as the class) and its model needs to be `@model XrefSubMenuToServices` and then you render it using just `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Xrefs)`

Comment: And ditto for the `Service` property - the template should be named `Service.cshtml` (in the `EditorTemplates` folder) and use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Service)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right, that's why the binder is getting confused. I missed that so just gave a solution. But that doesn't conflict with what I've said? And the *name* of EditorTemplate views is completely irrelevant, it's only used for finding them. There is no difference between `EditorFor(x => x.myString)` and `EditorFor(x => x.myString, "String.cshtml")` in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: @ThomasBoby, Sorry, but that is wrong. Look at the very last name/value pair in the Request values - its `Xrefs.MenuLocationTypeCode=` but property `Xrefs` is a collection. In order to bind, it needs to be `Xrefs[1].MenuLocationTypeCode=...`, `Xrefs.MenuLocationTypeCode=....` etc (i.e. with indexers). The indexers will not be added if you specify a template name. The template must be in the `EditorTemplates` folder (either in `Views/Shared/` or `Views/controllerName/`) and it must have the same name as the class

Comment: @ThomasBoby, What your referring to is a template name for a simple value type, but it will not work for a collection of complex objects. And the `id` has nothing to do with what is posted. Successful controls post name/value pairs based on the `name` and `value` attributes of the control.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just added the code with an Xrefs[n] syntax in a POST (which wasn't the problem). Before I wasn't including it to simplify the problem. Thank you for linking me to another similar question with a write up.